# Images for sticky posts

Tags: sticky-post

I have a sticky post that gets the image from background URL, but doesn't resize the image and leaves [my blog](http://brancadenoiva.com.br/2015/) heavy. Here is the code:

```
// is sticky 
if ( ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) ) {
    $sticky = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );
    $query = new WP_Query( 'p=' . $sticky[0] );;
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 1, //get all post
        'post__in' => get_option( 'sticky_posts' ), //are they sticky post
        'ignore_sticky_posts'=> 1
    );

    // The Query
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    // The Loop 
    // We are only getting a list of the title as a li, see the loop docs for details 
    //     on the loop, or copy this from index.php (or posts.php)
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();

        $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'slide-home' ); ?>       
        <div class="post post-big"  style="background:url(<?php echo $image[0]; ?>) no-repeat center; background-size: cover">
            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">
                <div class="info info-big">
                    <div class="overlay"></div>
                    <h2 class="title-post centered">
                        <div>
                            <?php
                            foreach( ( get_the_category() ) as $category ) {
                                if ( $category->category_parent == 0 ) {
                                    echo '<i class="icon icon-ico-categoria-' . 
                                        $category->cat_ID . '"></i>';
                                }
                            }
                            ?>
                        </div>
                        <?php the_title(); ?>
                    </h2>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
    wp_reset_query();
}
?></div>
```

How can I get the images regenerated, to set the site lighter?

Comment: Your code is pulling the size you specified, whatever that is. It isn't clear exactly what you are asking.

Comment: All your images are HUGE! Use s Chrome extension Perfmap - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/perfmap/hgpnhiajcdppfbogcpfdgcceepgkhdmk - which will show you even your smaller images take about 1 second to load.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to use responsive images in WP 4.4. Not a heck of a lot of documentation out yet but refer to this WP Core article [Responsive Images in WordPress 4.4](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/11/10/responsive-images-in-wordpress-4-4/).

Here is the example they give.

```
<?php
$img_src = wp_get_attachment_image_url( $attachment_id, 'medium' );
$img_srcset = wp_get_attachment_image_srcset( $attachment_id, 'medium' );
?>
<img src="<?php echo esc_url( $img_src ); ?>"
     srcset="<?php echo esc_attr( $img_srcset ); ?>"
     sizes="(max-width: 50em) 87vw, 680px" alt="A rad wolf">
```

If you go the lazy loading route check out [lazySizes](http://afarkas.github.io/lazysizes/#examples) - [bgset plugin](https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes/tree/gh-pages/plugins/bgset) / [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/trixta/bfqqnosp/embedded/result/). That would reduce your code to:

```
<?php
    $img_srcset = wp_get_attachment_image_srcset( $attachment_id, 'medium' );
    ?>
<div class="lazyload" data-bgset="<?php echo $img_srcset; ?>" data-sizes="auto">
```

This method ensures a smaller screen size won't require a full image, thus reducing your page load and site speed.

Answer (score -1):

I've already fixed the problem. Sorry for posting in portuguese.
I've had some problems with CSS because i needed to put some gradient in the image, but its ok now.

```
        <?php 
        //is sticky 
        if((is_home() || is_front_page()) ){

        $sticky = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );
        $query = new WP_Query( 'p=' . $sticky[0] );;
        $args = array(
            'posts_per_page' => 1, //get all post
            'post__in' => get_option( 'sticky_posts' ), //are they sticky post
            'ignore_sticky_posts'=> 1
        );

        // The Query
        $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

        // The Loop //we are only getting a list of the title as a li see the loop docs for details on the loop or copy this from index.php (or posts.php)

        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
            $the_query->the_post();

            ?> 
            <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'slide-home' ); ?>     
            <div class="post post-big">

                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">
                    <div class="info info-big">
                    <div class="behind"></div>
                        <div class="overlay"></div>
                        <div class="ahead">
                        <?php if( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                            if( is_sticky() ) the_post_thumbnail( 'sticky-post-thumbnail' );
                            else the_post_thumbnail();
                        }?>
                        </div>
                        <h2 class="title-post centered">
                            <div>
                                <?php
                                    foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) {
                                        if ($category->category_parent == 0) {
                                            echo '<i class="icon icon-ico-categoria-' . $category->cat_ID . '"></i>';
                                        }
                                    }
                                ?>
                            </div>
                            <?php the_title(); ?>
                        </h2>


                    </div>
                </a>

                </div>
            <?php
            }
            wp_reset_query();
            }
        ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please, write in English. Else we will delete this answer. Thank you.

Comment: The stack language is English. Answers should be in English.